# In mathematics, what is coefficient if variable is not having any coefficient in percentage equation?

Tags: arithmetic

If I am having equation as **X-14.8%X = 5.98**, then what is coefficient of variable X? Is it 1% or 100%?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Some additional details would be helpful, but right now, it looks like this is just an unusual way to write $x-0.148x=5.98$, since $14.8\%=0.148$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.